# As for a purpose

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of this phrase: **as for a purpose**. I found it in the following sentence:

> He is robbing me of my fruitful energy as for a purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He is robbing me of my fruitful energy as for a purpose.

**purpose** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/purpose)

> fixed intention in doing something; determination; firmness of purpose

As in:

He is robbing me of my fruitful energy with a singular determination. (to do so)

Much like on purpose - intentionally.